# why vnoremap a A takes seconds to complete?

Tags: vim, editor, neovim

i have this in my config file:

```
nnoremap a a
vnoremap a A
```

and pressing a in visual mode takes 2 seconds to do the action

why is this happening? is this a bad practice?

Comment: you have other mappings starting with `a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is being caused by the fact that you have something **else** mapped (either in visual mode or in all modes) that starts with 'a'.

Imagine I map 2 different commands in my .vimrc (or as you called it, config file)

> vnoremap a A
>   vnoremap ab D

Here, when I press 'a' in visual mode, I want it to append text. 
When I press 'ab' I want it to delete a row for me instead.

I now reach over to my keyboard and I press 'ab'. How does vim know I wanted to delete a line and not just append the letter 'b' to the text? Both require the same keypresses.

So to tell the difference, **when I hit the 'a' key, vim waits a second to see which command I choose**, If I press 'b' quickly it will realize that this is actually the instruction 'ab' which means 'D' which means delete.

If I press 'a' and wait a second, vim will accept that I was issuing the instruction 'a' which means 'A' which means append. I then hit 'b' and the letter 'b' is appended to the text.

If you want it to stop, you will have to go through your .vimrc and change your mappings to not overlap (start with the same letters) as much, or you can type
`:h leader`
in vim and learn about mapleaders, which will make it much easier for you to plan your mappings. I have my mapleader set to space personally but many people also like to use commas or some other key of their choosing.

**tldr: Vim is waiting a second to see if you are going to press another key and issue a different command**

Comment: thanks! i should have thought of that. I saw an action is mapped with `a%` in visual mode in `map`, but `map a% <nop>` still can't overwrite the original mapping, how is this happening?

Comment: @wengwengweng well, when you type :map, what does it tell you that a% is mapped to? did you try vnoremap a%  <nop> ?

what does the line from :map say?

Comment: well running `vnoremap a% <nop>` in vim works, but it still waits, so `unmap a%` works better. but if i put either one in my `.vimrc` they won't run (the map doesn't exist yet), so is that mapping added by a plugin which is loaded after `.vimrc`?

Comment: i managed to do it by creating scripts in the `after` folder, thanks

Comment: @wengwengweng it's probably from something from a plugin because plugins are run after vimrc. I highly recommend that you rather set your mapleader. Then you just put the mapleader in front of any commands you write yourself. For example my mapleader is space, so for my mapping to open or close a fold, I press <space>f. This way I don't get in the way of whatever f is mapped to, even if I don't know what f is mapped to. 

Try it, one of the things about vim is that it feels much better when you use it the way its intended and not the first way that works.